# Making a template meta function to create a unit matrix at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

I was asking myself if it is possible to create a unit matrix at compile time if size is known. So far I just wrote an example creating a std::vector based matrix with a fixed size, e.g. 4x4. However, I am not sure how to set the values. I guess, I need recursion :/

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
using vec1D = std::vector<T>;

template <class T>
using vec2D = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

template <class T, int size>
vec2D<T> make_mat() {
  vec2D<T> mat(size, vec1D<T>(size));
  return mat;
}

int main()
{
  vec2D<float> unit = make_mat<float, 4>();
  std::cout 
  << unit[0][0] << unit[0][1] << unit[0][2] << unit[0][3] << std::endl
  << unit[1][0] << unit[1][1] << unit[1][2] << unit[1][3] << std::endl
  << unit[2][0] << unit[2][1] << unit[2][2] << unit[2][3] << std::endl
  << unit[3][0] << unit[3][1] << unit[3][2] << unit[3][3] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I am sure you can do it, but it is beyond my level. Wait for the visit of a template-metaprogramming master.

Comment: I just try to learn a bit about template-metaprogramming. However, it is tricky to master and there are not many examples to learn from.

Comment: If you have small matrices, just write all cases, it will be much faster in terms of programmer time. Understanding your code won't require to be metaprogramming master. If you have big matrices, hard-writing them in your executable might not be faster than generating them at runtime. And compared to the cost of an allocation, you will probably not be optimizing the right thing. Try to optimize programmer time as well as execution time.

Comment: My question was created out of curiosity. Creating a matrix at run time is just boring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was asking myself if it is possible to create a unit matrix at compile time if size is known.

I don't think so if your matrix is `std::vector` based.

But if it's based on `std::array` and you want it initialized to zero (as in your example) yes: it's possible.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename T, std::size_t D1, std::size_t D2 = D1>
constexpr std::array<std::array<T, D2>, D1> doA ()
 { return { }; }

int main()
{
  constexpr auto unit = doA<float, 4U>();

  std::cout 
  << unit[0][0] << unit[0][1] << unit[0][2] << unit[0][3] << std::endl
  << unit[1][0] << unit[1][1] << unit[1][2] << unit[1][3] << std::endl
  << unit[2][0] << unit[2][1] << unit[2][2] << unit[2][3] << std::endl
  << unit[3][0] << unit[3][1] << unit[3][2] << unit[3][3] << std::endl;
}
```

But I don't think is a good idea: take in count that `std::array` use the stack, not the heap. So this solution is useful only for little (very little) matrices.

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP (correctly) observe

> question was whether on could init the matrix as unit matrix: 100 010 001

Yes, it's possible with unit matrix too; a little more complicated but possible.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template <typename T, std::size_t I, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto doU_helper2 (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>
    { { (Is == I ? T{1} : T{0})... } }; }

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto doU_helper1 (std::index_sequence<Is...> const & is)
 { return std::array<std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)>, sizeof...(Is)>
    { { doU_helper2<T, Is>(is)... } }; }

template <typename T, std::size_t Dim>
constexpr auto doU ()
 { return doU_helper1<T>(std::make_index_sequence<Dim>{}); }

int main()
{
  constexpr auto unit = doU<float, 4U>();

  std::cout 
  << unit[0][0] << unit[0][1] << unit[0][2] << unit[0][3] << std::endl
  << unit[1][0] << unit[1][1] << unit[1][2] << unit[1][3] << std::endl
  << unit[2][0] << unit[2][1] << unit[2][2] << unit[2][3] << std::endl
  << unit[3][0] << unit[3][1] << unit[3][2] << unit[3][3] << std::endl;
}
```

Take in count that this code use `std::make_index_sequence{}` and `std::index_sequence`, that are C++14 feature.

If you need a C++11 solution, it's not too much difficult create a subtitute; ask if you need it (somewhere I've done; I've only to retrieve).

Comment: @ c++shell the output is all zero

Comment: @dgrat - yes: as in your example; the matrix is initialized with zero values. Do you expecting something different?

Comment: question was whether on could init the matrix as unit matrix:
100
010
001

Comment: @dgrat - D'Oh! You're right; sorry, I didn't noticed the "unit" part. Yes, it's possible with unit matrices too; only a little more complicated (3 `constexpr` functions instead of 1). Improved my answer with an example.

Comment: Looks still nice :)

Comment: You need to inlcude btw #include <utility>

Comment: @dgrat - strange; g++ and clang++ don't complain; but you're right: `std::index_sequence` require `<utility>`. Anyway, I remember you: use this solution only for very small unit matrices: `std::array` use stack memory. For bigger matrices you can use the same solution with `std::vector`, that use heap memory, but you can't use `constexpr` so you're matrices are initialized run time.

Comment: My intention was anyway to use it only for 3x3 or maybe 4x4 matrices which are defined in headers. I just thought that header definitions like this are not very nice nor flexible.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do dynamic allocation at compile time.

You can do it at runtime.  The easy way is with loops.

If you want to avoid loops completely:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
auto index_over(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto){
    return decltype(f)(f)(std::integral_constant<std::size_t,Is>{}...);
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto index_upto(std::integral_constant<std::size_t,N> ={}){
  return index_over(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template <class T>
using vec1D = std::vector<T>;

template <class T>
using vec2D = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t I,class T>
vec1D<T> make_row( T const& base, T const& diag ){
  return index_upto<I>()([&](auto...Before){
    return index_upto<N-I-1>()([&](auto...After)->vec1D<T>{
      return {
        (void(Before), base)...,
        diag,
        (void(After), base)...
      };
    });
  });
}

template<std::size_t N, class T>
vec2D<T> make_mat( T const& base, T const& diag){
  return index_upto<N>()([&}(auto...Rs)->vec2D<T>{
    return {
      make_row<N, Rs>(base, diag)...
    };
  });
}
```

may contain typos (written on phone, not tested).  Uses constructs that are valid C++ but g++ chokes on sometimes; clang will understand it.  C++14.

Index upto and over avoids having to write a pile of helper functions to expand index parameter packs; they let you do the expansion in a lambda.

If your compiler complains about `Rs` being used at compile time, replace with `decltype(Rs)::value` -- your compiler has a `constexpr` evaluation failure.

Doing this in C++11 is annoying.  I might use helper types to do the pack expansion, one per function I wrote above.  You'd also want to rewrite index sequence from C++14.  It is very meh, just do loop.

```
auto u = make_mat<4>( 0, 1 );
```

makes a diagonal matrix of `int`, size 4x4.

Note that this technique, with liberal `constexpr` and sizing and types, works with std array.  Sadly lambda cannot be constexpr until C++17.

The loop solution also works with `constexpr` matrices post C++14; you can mutate local data in constexpr.